# What Are Some Good Open Source Project Landing Pages?

Tags: templates

I've built a pretty extensive open source project that I'm soon going to publish online. It's got full documentation, source, and everything else you'd expect from a project, but no website.

I've been looking around for inspiration, and found some great open source website examples written by the pocoo team, for example:

- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)
- [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)

The problem is, I'm not a designer, and can't make web designs if my life depends on it.

So my question is: are there any good HTML/CSS templates out there that would be suitable to use for an open source project? Preferably something simple that shows off a bit of code, and links to docs, help, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) is a documentation system that should be able to help you out. It's very popular in the Python community, and actually those pages you pointed out utilize this tool, as well---look at the bottom of the pages. The [official Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/index.html) uses it, too.

It uses the [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) markup language, so that's what you'd need to read up on if you're not already familiar with it.

Comment: I'm using Sphinx for my project's docs, but is it suitable for a front-page?

Comment: @b14ck I've seen projects websites that are purely Sphinx-generated, sure. You don't have to over-complicate things. If you want, though, you could probably fork the Flask site itself and modify the content on it to suit your own purposes. I don't know of any proper templates, though.